# Path of html file for eclipse plugin

Tags: html, eclipse, maven, plugins

I am creating an eclipse plugin using Eclipse Luna for RCP and RAP Developers 4.4.2. This plugin is built using maven (and tycho). Coding is done in java, javascript and html. For the graphic part, a html file is used:

```
String INDEX_HTML = "main/resources/res/www/index.html";
String basePath= ClassName.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
File mHtmlFile = new File(basePath + INDEX_HTML);
mBrowser.setUrl(mHtmlFile.toURI().toString());
```

I have specified the class containg all this in plugin.xml. (Tell me if the content of plugin.xml is needed to solve this)

Now the problem is that when I Build the project and put the resulting jar in dropins of Eclipse, it displays the message "Cannot display the page". (Whereas the jar is containing the html file in 'main/resources/res/www').
When I hardcode the path of the html file, it works perfectly.

Kindly, tell me how to solve this without hardcoding the path of html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just one HTML which does not reference other resources in the plugin you can get a 'file' type URL using:

```
Bundle bundle = ... your plugin bundle

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("file path in the plugin"), null);

url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

`FileLocator.toFileURL` may extract the file from the jar and put it in a temporary location.

If the HTML references other resources you may need to use

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

in the plugin MANIFEST.MF. This will build the plugin as a directory rather than a jar so that files in the plugin can be referenced without copying.

Note: If you are using a 'feature' build the 'unpack' option in the 'feature.xml' overrides the bundle shape.

You can get the `Bundle` using:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

(this must be run in a class in the plugin)

You can also use:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

which can be used to get any bundle.

Comment: Our project is not using OSGi bundles... It is built as a jar using maven.

Comment: How you build it makes no difference, if it is an Eclipse plugin this applies.

Comment: We don't have much idea about OSGi. Can you please specify what should be written after: Bundle bundle= ??  (Since we have not created a bundle for our project)

Comment: Thanks for the code. It worked perfectly. But the html file is using js and css files too. I have tried the approach (Eclipse-BundleShape:dir) that you suggested earlier. But its of no use. The effects are not visible. If you have any alternative then please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers do not know how to show web pages from within a jar file. You will need to make a copy of the HTML file, at runtime, using a utility like the FileLocator. One call to `find()` a URL to that file within the jar, another to extract it and return that copy's `file:` URL.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FFileLocator.html&anchor=toFileURL(java.net.URL)

Comment: It is not running on browser. It's an eclipse plugin and will run on Eclipse platform only.

Comment: This is a maven-plugin and its not bundled we are building it and creating its jar. Will this solution be possible ??.